# Constructing a model of Replacement

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Suppose we started with a set $A$ and wanted to define the closure T of $A$ under Replacement. Does the following recursive definition work?

$T_0 = A$

$T_{\alpha+1} = T_{\alpha} \cup\hspace{2mm} \{t\hspace{1.5mm} |\hspace{2mm} \exists x \in X (f(x)=t) : X \in T_{\alpha} ,f:X \rightarrow V  \}$

$T_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} T_\beta$ for $\alpha$ limit.

Let $T = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \textrm{ORD}} T_{\alpha}$

Then $T \models$ Replacement.

Proof: $T$ is transitive by construction, hence it suffices to show that whenever $X \in$ T and $f: X \rightarrow T$, then $rng(f) \in T$. 
So, let $X \in$ T and $f: X \rightarrow T$. Then $X \in T_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. Let $v \in rng(f)$. Then $\exists u$ such that $f(u) = v$. Since $dom(f) = X$ and $X \in T_{\alpha}$, $u \in X$. Hence $v \in T_{\alpha+1}$.  Therefore $rng(f) \subseteq T_{\alpha+1} \in$ T. So $rng(f) \in T$ as required.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your successor step - as written, we just get $T_{\alpha+1}=T_\alpha$ (all the new $t$s have to be in the range of $f$,  whose codomain is $T_\alpha$). I think you want to write instead something like $$T_{\alpha+1}=T_\alpha\cup\{\{t: \exists x\in X(f(x)=t)\}: X\in T_\alpha, f:X\rightarrow T_\alpha\}.$$ That said, there seems to be some context missing: what makes you suspect that there is an issue with this type of argument?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think one problem with the proof might be that the assumption of $f:X \rightarrow T$ doesn't satisfy the condition on the set of $t$ in $T_{\alpha+1}$, namely, that $f$ be a function into $T_{\alpha}$, not $T$. Can I instead just define $T_{\alpha+1}$ as:$T_{\alpha+1} = T_{\alpha} \cup\hspace{2mm} \{t\hspace{1.5mm} |\hspace{2mm} \exists x \in X (f(x)=t) : X \in T_{\alpha} ,f:X \rightarrow V \}$

Comment: Why is $T$ transitive by construction?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's not, my mistake.